# Passing multiple strings into a function

Tags: c

i am trying to read several strings into a function for processing. The instructions are to pass each string into the function (not create a 2d array of strings). The parameters must stay the same. Here is what i tried

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void convert(char s[]), int counts[]);

int main(void)
{
     int i = 0;
     int d[2] = {};
     char text0[] = "this IS a String 4 you."; 
     char text1[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.";
     while(i<2)
     {
         convert (text[i],d); """ this is wrong but i dont know how to correctly do this
         i = i +1;
     }

}

void convert(char s[]), int counts[])
{

printf("%s this should print text1 and text2", s );

}
```

So i have a couple of questions. Is there some sort of special character/operator similiar to the glob module in python that can correctly do the `convert (text[i],d)` part for me where i try to read in each string. Also the `int counts[]` purpose is to be filled in with the word and character count in the function. So if i fill in this array in function `convert`will main also recognize it since i need to print the word/character count in `main` without returning the actual counts in `convert`

Comment: `text0` and `text[0]` are completely different variables.

Comment: yea thats where im stuck. i want to do something like that but im not sure how

Answer (score 1):

You could use temporary string pointer array to pass all strings:

```
    char text1[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.";
    char const * texts[] = { text0, text1 };
    convert (texts, 2, d);
}

void convert(char const * s[], size_t n, int counts[]) 
{
    while(n--) {
        *counts++ = strlen(*s);
        printf("%s\n", *s++);
    }
}
```

Some notes:

1. I added `char const` to function argument type. You should always do that when function does not change the string. If you need to change the string in function, just remove the `const`.
2. There is extra argument `size_t n` to pass array array element count to function. `size_t` can be found in `stddef.h`.

Answer (score 0):

i think u lost a "(" in "void convert(char s[]), int counts[]);".
it should be void convert((char s[]), int counts[]);

Comment: Yours is not an answer, suggestions like this must be given as comments to user's post.

Comment: @MadHatter Perhaps his reputation score doesn't allow him post a comment http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment

Comment: how can i get reputation? @MadHatter Perhaps,@nodakai

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void convert(char s[], int counts[]);

int main(void){
    int i = 0;
    int d[2] = {0};
    char text0[] = "this IS a String 4 you."; 
    char text1[] = "This sample has less than 987654321 leTTers.";
    char *text[] = { text0, text1 };
    for(i=0; i<2; ++i){
        convert (text[i], d);
        printf("%d, %d\n", d[0], d[1]);
    }

}

void convert(char s[], int counts[]){
    printf("%s\n", s );
    {
        char *temp = strdup(s);
        char *word, *delimiter = " \t\n";//Word that are separated by space character.
        int count_w=0, max_len=0;
        for(word = strtok(temp, delimiter); word ; word = strtok(NULL, delimiter)){
            int len = strlen(word);
            if(max_len < len)
                max_len = len;
            ++count_w;
        }
        counts[0] = count_w;
        counts[1] = max_len;
        free(temp);
    }
}
```